# AutoLPG Car Stops While Idling

Tags: hyundai, scheduled-maintenance, lpg

I had bought AutoLPG Car Hyundai EON and after 6 Years of Usage, now car is having an issue of stopping while idling or it seems it will stop.

What preventive measures should we take for AutoLPG cars after few years? Are there any wear and tear parts in AutoLPG cars which need timely replacement?

Comment: Hi Mitesh, your q1 is a very different one to Q2 and q3. I have edited your post to remove it so your question can be answered, but please feel free to ask it in another post.